# javascript styling element with custom function

Tags: javascript, function, object, styling, assign

I want to style element in javascript easily but this function doesn't work

```
const addStyles = function (el, styles) {
    Object.assign(el.style, styles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the element first, then access the `style` property (it's a string) and set your CSS there.

Here's an example. As you can see the text is black and there is no CSS, however, with the javascript line I can make it red.

```js
function addStyles(element, style) {
  element.style = style;
}


const myElement = document.getElementById("myText");

addStyles(myElement, "color: red; font-size: 25px;");
```

```html
<p id="myText">Some text<p>
```

Comment: I know that but I want sth like that
`
addStyles(span, {
    width: "200px",
    height: "300px",
    background: "#fa00ff"
});

Comment: it says: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set an indexed property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': Indexed property setter is not supported.

Comment: It means you're probably getting wrong the element. In the example above it works. Feel free to add more details in the question with your code.